# Passpharase Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, 20.04, encryption

After installing Ubuntu 20.04 on new Lenovo Thinkpad I found my hard disk locked.

When I tried to unlock it, it asks for "passpharase" which I do not know. How can I unlock my disk? Where can I find this passphrase?

Comment: You created the passphrase (key) when you encrypted your files or disk, which is an option (not required) in the installer. At the time, you were warned not to lose or forget your key, and perhaps should write it down. There is no way to "recover" or "find" this passphrase on the system -- that would defeat the entire purpose of encryption (which is to deny access to everybody who lacks the key, forever). You must search your memory.

Comment: @user535733 I would like to add a follow-up question: is there a limit on the tries? Someone might have forgotten the correct passphrase but dimly remember the outline, giving it a try for various versions, like typos in the original passphrase. Or will Ubuntu erase the whole disc on the third false try? And, is there a way to backup the whole image, to have some extra tries?

Comment: If you can't recall your passphrase, you can also just re-install the OS (make sure to format the drives in the process). As mentioned, it's up to you to remember it. If you don't want that feature, don't chose it when installing.

Comment: @KGIII with reinstalling, all private data will be lost.

Comment: I did choose normal instalation and after Erase disk and install ubuntu. Yeah there was a place where I wrote some password I remember that, but it did not unclock it after entering that password.

Comment: Seems like time to re-install, then. Unless, of course, this is some non-Ubuntu disk encryption (like Windows BitLocker or similar). We're assuming that you --perhaps erroneously-- clicked the installer checkbox to install Ubuntu encryption. The term "passphrase" is usually *only* used in encryption, and you mentioned that it was a new install. If there are other factors involved, like dual-boot, mention those. If not, then go ahead and re-install.

Comment: Try booting again and write down if it asks for passphrase or password.  The two are different and password will be easier to fix.  Password for login, passphrase for encryption.

Comment: How to re-install than properly ? Should I erase disk again ?

Comment: @user535733 how to re-install properly ?

Comment: Yes, erase your disk again.

Comment: @GyroGearloose, indeed they will lose their private data and that's the entire point. They can't access their data because it's irreversibly encrypted, so it's useless to them. Why would they keep data that has zero value to anyone, including them?

Comment: I solved. While re-installing I did choose something else and deleted all partitions. After I added just what is required to install and left all free space just unused. Once installation is done you can control all your free space in Disks.